# Pushing one directory to a new repository

Tags: git, git-subtree

I have a repository of legacy code, and I'd like to push one directory to a new repo.

So basically from `repo A`, I want to push `/react_code` to the root of `repo B` and keep history.

Help is much appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Check out the ["subtree" merge strategy](https://git-scm.com/docs/merge-strategies#Documentation/merge-strategies.txt-subtreeltpathgt)

Comment: `cd A && git subtree push -P react_code intermediate_repo` then `cd B && git subtree pull -P react_code intermediate_repo`